# RS hashing program

Tags: algorithm, hash

Can anyone please tell me the working principle or algorithm for the RS string hashing algorithm? I need it, but cannot find on google. Please help me with the algorithm atleast, i would implement it on my own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean [Robert Sedgewick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Sedgewick_%28computer_scientist%29)'s string hashing algorithm?

```
uint a = 63689, uint b = 378551
foreach ( byte x ; bytes ) {
    value = value * a + x;
    a *= b;
}
return value;
```

(quoted from from http://pallas.telperion.info/d/hash/).

Comment: could you please tell which language is this code snippet written in?

Comment: It's in D (at least according to the original site).  Hopefully it's pretty simple to copy over to the language of your choice.

Comment: The pallas link is broken. Any way you can update it? Thanks. Also does this hashing work with vector of integers?

Comment: @JeffFoster Why don't worry about the overflow when calling `a *= b;`?

Comment: Overflow is irrelevant since we're not trying to create a "right" answer, but a consistent one.

Answer (score 0):

Python implementation is as below:

```
def RSHash(key):
    a = 63689
    b = 378551
    hash = 0
    for i in range(len(key)):
        hash = hash * a + ord(key[i])
        a = a * b
return hash
```

Comment: The "hash" is not truncated to 32-bit. This code returns a really really long hash.

Comment: Why don't worry about the overflow when calling a *= b;?

Answer (score 0):

C++ Implementation is as below:

```
unsigned int RSHash(const std::string& str)
{
   unsigned int b    = 378551;
   unsigned int a    = 63689;
   unsigned int hash = 0;

   for(std::size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
   {
      hash = hash * a + str[i];
      a    = a * b;
   }

   return hash;
}
/* End Of RS Hash Function */
```